# Is it possible to add CI info in push?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, runner

We are using Gitlab CE and Gitlab Runner for our CI/CD on our Stage Servers. We got a branch for lets say dev1 where we need to do different tasks for different changes.

E.g. for frontend stuff we need a compiler to start and for backend we need to run php-unit.

Can I decide in the push what kind of Pipeline I want to start? I saw tags but they are different in git (for versioning) and gitlab (for runners) I suppose.

Is there a best practive for that use case or do I have to use 2 different branches?

Answer (score 0):

You can define two manual tasks for dev1 branch, and decide on your own which task to invoke.

```
run-php-unit:
stage: build
script:
  - echo "Running php unit"
when: manual
only: dev1

start-compiler:
stage: build
script:
  - echo "Starting compiler"
when: manual
only: dev1
```